# How to write C# code to add a new Range or edit in AGauge?

Tags: c#, winforms, collections

I am writing a C# code for school to display simulated values using AGauge.
I wanted to write as a code to add new range instead of using editor.

On the attached link, it is mentioned that it is possible using code.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/448721/AGauge-WinForms-Gauge-Control

Can you please explain how can this be done as there is no code example on this weblink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do this with the editor, you can find the corresponding code in the auto-generated file named xx.Designer.cs.

Originally everyone has to write code in a primitive editor like Notepad, but later Visual Studio (and other IDE) provides us with a nice designer and also *translates* what we input in the designer to the the actual code, and use the actual code in the compilation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i will check!